# Win7pe_SE based recovery disk using multiple wim's

Tags: rescue-disk, bartpe

I have been trying to build a multi wim recovery disk that is supposedly possible in win7pese but have not been successfull in booting the image with the built in tools.  I can select either option from the boot menu but it always loads the wim file that was just created.  I was hoping some one had a suggestion as to why this is happening.  If i swap the wim files the other build starts working as expected so the wim files them selves are good but for some reason the utility is not building a proper boot file.

Comment: Since rebootpro and theoven forums are ignoring new user requests I finally reinstalled the software a 3rd time on a new version of the pc image and it started working for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/multi_boot-wim   outlines how to create a single wim file with multiple wim images inside saving space by consolidating duplicated files. this may be used to combine multiple versions of os's unsure how it will work with win8 and win7 there may be an update on that page for such.